# What do you call someone who is aroused by strangling someone to death?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the terminology for someone who is aroused by strangling someone to death?

Albert DeSilva, the Boston Strangler, was a(n) ________.

I realize *sadist* covers this but I was hoping for a more specific term.

Comment: Define *[aroused](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arouse)* for this question. Do you mean any arousal or do you necessarily mean sexual arousal?

Comment: Erotophonophilia - People  sexually aroused by attempts of killing someone.  https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/in-excess/201308/thrilling-killing-and-the-disgust-lust not necessarily by strangling someone. But this is much more specific than paraphilia.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's looking for a technical term in a specific discipline.

Comment: @Clare Thank you. I'm finding more and more how this community just likes to close the question as off-topic rather than help. I will use Erotophonophilia thank you

Comment: Two of the close votes were because "questions...should include information on how [the word] will be used". The OP did that. One vote was because of lack of research; this close vote could be argued either way on this question. The fourth vote would eliminate any question that is a technical term in any discipline. And an adequately referenced answer by an MD to a medical question was downvoted. Not ELU's finest afternoon

Comment: You're asking us to diagnose the guy.

Comment: @PeterLynch you did not do yourself a favor by not clarifying your question.

Comment: The FBI categorizes *most* serial killings as **"Sexual Homicides"**; as such, Albert DeSilva was a *serial killer* and more particularly a **sexual sadist.** Refer to the published works of John Douglas and Robert Ressler for more information.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is one type of **paraphilia**.

_ "Albert DeSilva, the Boston Strangler, was a paraphilic individual or suffered from a paraphilic disorder."

> **[Paraphilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphilia)** (previously known as sexual perversion and sexual deviation) is the experience of intense sexual arousal to atypical objects, situations, fantasies, behaviors, or individuals.
>
> No consensus has been found for any precise border between unusual sexual interests and paraphilic ones.[2][3] There is debate over which, if any, of the paraphilias should be listed in diagnostic manuals, such as the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM) or the International Classification of Diseases (ICD).
> **The number and taxonomy of paraphilia is under debate; one source lists as many as 549 types of paraphilia.**

Comment: Also your answer could benefit from an authoritative source.

Comment: @Clare   I agree that Wikipedia isn't the best of references but that specific article quotes really authoritative sources such as the American Psychiatric Association and the DSM.  Other reliable sources I found, such as https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/291419-overview  and https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/mental-illness/basics/tests-diagnosis/con-20033813 are paid sites which I subscribe and it wouldn't help much if I included them.

Answer (score 0):

*Albert DeSilva, the Boston Strangler, was a **lust murderer**.*

From a [psychologytoday.com](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/shadow-boxing/201501/the-lust-murderer-asocial-vs-nonsocial) blog:

> Erotophonophilia is a sexual paraphilia in which individuals derive sexual pleasure and arousal from murdering (or imagining they are murdering) someone. Many academics in the forensic field refer to such killings as **‘lust murder’**.

From  another [psychologytoday.com](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/in-excess/201308/thrilling-killing-and-the-disgust-lust) blog:

> They didn’t invent **“lust murderer”** as a category. That’s been in criminology circles for well over a century. But they did add behavioral nuances that they hoped would assist investigators.

Also http://www.practicalhomicide.com/articles/lustmurder.htm which is so horrible I'd rather not quote from it.